# useState hook being called inside map function causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently building a dynamic form engine and I want to display results from the redux store when the Answer Summary component is rendered. The way I figured would be best to do this would be to having a 'complete' status and set it to true once the answerSummary component is loaded, but doing this within the map function does not work and throws the infinite loop react error.

Code is here:

```
function App() {
  let [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Form App Prototype</h1>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {Object.values(Database.steps).map(step => {
            step.name === 'answerSummary' ? setComplete(true) : setComplete(false);
            return (

              <Route exact path={`/${step.name}`} render={() =>
                <Step step={step} />

              }
              />
            )
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
        <br></br>
        <div style={{display: complete? 'block' : 'none'}}><StoreVisual/></div>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

EDIT: I know you aren't able to setState inside the render - I've written it this way as a way to try and convey what I want to be able to do

Comment: it seems you don't know what is the concept of react. You should NEVER set your state inside the return render. Setting state causes the render function to get called. And that's how you get infinite loop.

Comment: Just edited to explain - I understand that, I've just written it that way to try and show what I want to be able to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to render `<StoreVisual/>` when they are on the last step it might be easier to set up a state hook for the index of the step people are on.

```
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
```

Every time someone progresses a step increment this value.

You would have to pass `setIndex`, or whatever you call your setter, into the `Step` component to do this.

Then you can render `<StoreVisual/>` with a conditional, like so...

```
<div>
      <h1>Claimer Form App Prototype</h1>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {Object.values(Database.steps).map(step => 
              <Route exact 
                     path={`/${step.name}`} 
                     render={() => <Step step={step} /> }/> )}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
        <br></br>
        {Database.steps[index] === 'answerSummary' && <StoreVisual/>}
    </div>
```

This approach also affords you a simple way to let people start in the middle of the form. Say you want to let people save half-finished forms in the future, you just change/update the default value of index hook.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your problem is that you are trying to display results after the answer summary component is mounted.
You can achieve this by using the `useEffect` hook which runs when the component mounts. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set state inside render which cause infinite loop.[Whenever state is changed, component will re-render(calls render function)]

render()=>setState()=>render()=>setState().......infinite

WorkAround:

```
<div style={{display: this.props.location.pathname=='answerSummary'? 'block' : 'none'}}><StoreVisual/></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that aspect of it and why it causes the loop - do you know if there's a workaround at all?

Comment: I have updated my answer which i think can solve your problem without infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running that code inline in your return, build the array in your function logic:

```
function App() {
  let [complete, setComplete] = useState(false);
  // build an array of Route components before rendering
  // you should also add a unique key prop to each Route element
  const routes = Object.values(Database.steps).map(step => {
    step.name === 'answerSummary' ? setComplete(true) : setComplete(false);
    return <Route exact path={`/${step.name}`} render={() => <Step step={step} />} />
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Claimer Form App Prototype</h1>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          // render the array 
          {[routes]}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <br></br>
      <div style={{display: complete? 'block' : 'none'}}><StoreVisual/></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't think you need to call `setComplete(false)` based on this logic, so you should probably replace your ternary with an if statement:

```
if (step.name === 'answerSummary') {
  setComplete(true)
}
```

and avoid making unnecessary function calls